# Цикл по переменным

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Что есть:

```
@{
    int Ach1 = 3;
    int Ach2 = 300;
    int Ach3 = 500000;
}
@{ Ach1++; }@Ach1
```

Всё просто, получаем на выходе 4. А как быть если мне нужно перебирать их? То есть по сути мне нужно прибавлять единичку не =3, а к int Ach1 и получить int Ach2, int Ach3 и так далее.
Нужно генерировать эти данные из массива в 1 блок представления, а не плодить их кучу в представлении.

Собственно сам блок:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="well well-sm">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 text-center">
                <img src="~/images/ach/Ach1.png" alt="Ach"
                     class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9 section-box">
                <span class="ach-title-size">
                    Заголовок
                    @if (@info.Ach1 >= @Ach1 / 3)
                    {
                        <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
                    }
                    @if (@info.Ach1 >= @Ach1 / 3 * 2)
                    {
                        <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
                    }
                    @if (@info.Ach1 >= @Ach1)
                    {
                        <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
                    }
                </span>
                <p class="ach-text-size">
                    Инфо
                </p>
                @if (@info.@Ach1 >= Ach1)
                {
                    <dt class="text-warning">Выполнено!</dt>
                    ach_status = "completed";
                    <span>@ach_status</span>

                }
                else
                {
                    ach_status = "uncompleted";
                    <span class="pull-right ach-text-size">
                        @info.Ach1<span>/</span>@Ach1
                    </span>
                    <div class="row rating-desc">
                        <div class="col-md-12">
                            <div class="ach-progress">
                                <progress max="@Ach1" value="@info.Ach1">
                                </progress>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                }
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Кому не сложно, набросайте пожалуйста верный пример в консольке, или толкните в нужное русло. Спасибо!

По ходу решения вопроса - назрела более серьёзная сложность:

Как быть с базой тут же) Вот пример:

```
@foreach (Web.Models.DataBase.Achievements info in ViewBag.info) 
{ 
@if @info.Ach1 >= @Ach1 / 3) 
<span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning">
</span> 
}
```

В табличке базы данных Achievements все строки так же по порядку. Начиная с Ach1 и заканчивая Ach50. Собственно так же любопытно, на сколько это реально?

Comment: попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. То, что вы сейчас написали - я вроде слова отдельные понимаю, но все вместе просто какая то бессмыслица.

Comment: Спасибо за столь скорый ответ). В представлении объявил следующие позиции: @{
    int Ach1 = 3;
    int Ach2 = 300;
    int Ach3 = 500000;
} После чего ниже набросал блок и использовал данные значения. Но дело в том, что этих позиций у меня должно быть 50. Не клепать же мне 50 одинаковых блоков))). Вот и решил что-то думать с циклами. Хочу чтобы в дизайне был 1 блок и в него из цикла генерились по очереди все позиции. Ach1,Ach2,Ach3 и так далее.

Comment: Собственно не могу понять как сделать для примера массив из 3х элементов и к индексу массива прибавлять единичку. Чтобы в представлении можно было указать что-то вроде @{ Ach++; }@Ach и получить столько позиций, сколько в массиве. Потому как делать int Ach1 = 1, int Ach2 = 2 50 раз и столько же раз плодить  в представлении блоки вписывая эти int(ы) наверное не правильно)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это можно реализовать вот таким образом.

1. Добавьте Partial View. Например, `\Views\Shared\_Achievement.cshtml`.
2. Перенесите разметку для `Achievement` в Partial View, а в самой вьюхе отобразите Partial View используя метод `Html.Partial` и передавайте ей экземпляр `Achievement` через `Model`.

   ```
   @foreach (Web.Models.DataBase.Achievements info in ViewBag.info)
     <div class="col-md-6">
       <div class="well well-sm">
         <div class="row">
           @Html.Partial("_Achievement", info)
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   }
   /**/
   ```
3. В `_Achievement.cshtml` используйте `ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties`, чтобы перечислить все свойства и вывести их на экран.

   ```
   @{
     Dictionary<string, int> Achs = new Dictionary<string, int>() {
       { "Ach1", 3 },
       {"Ach2", 300 },
       {"Ach3", 500000 }
       };
     string ach_status;
   }

   @foreach (ModelMetadata property in ViewData.ModelMetadata.Properties) {
     if (property.PropertyName.StartsWith("Ach")) {
       <div class="col-xs-3 col-md-3 text-center">
         <img src="@string.Format("~/images/ach/{0}.png", property.PropertyName)" alt="Ach"
            class="img-rounded img-responsive" />
       </div>
       <div class="col-xs-9 col-md-9 section-box">
         <span class="ach-title-size">
           Заголовок
           @if ((int)property.Model >= Achs[property.PropertyName] / 3) {
             <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
           } else {
             <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
           }
           @if ((int)property.Model >= Achs[property.PropertyName] / 3 * 2) {
             <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
           } else {
             <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
           }
           @if ((int)property.Model >= Achs[property.PropertyName]) {
             <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
           } else {
             <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star-empty text-warning"></span>
           }
         </span>
         <p class="ach-text-size">
           Инфо
         </p>
         @if ((int)property.Model >= Achs[property.PropertyName]) {
           <div class="text-warning">Выполнено!</div>
           ach_status = "completed";
           <span>@ach_status</span>

         } else {
           ach_status = "uncompleted";
           <span class="pull-right ach-text-size">
             @property.Model<span>/</span>@Achs[property.PropertyName]
           </span>
           <div class="row rating-desc">
             <div class="col-md-12">
               <div class="ach-progress">
                 <progress max="@Achs[property.PropertyName]" value="@((int)(int)property.Model)">
                 </progress>
               </div>
             </div>
           </div>
         }
       </div>
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Простите. 3й пункт не совсем понятен (я новичок) http://prntscr.com/kw490i

Comment: @Ник, не могу открыть скриншот (Server Not Found). Но код, что приведен в третьем пункте, должен по идее без проблем заработать в вашем проекте, т.к. это слегка отредактированный ваш же код. Суть третьего пункта в том, что фреймворк по вашей модели создает метаданные (список свойств), которые вы можете перечислить и вывести на страницу так, как будто это обычный массив.

Comment: Странно очень. Перезалил скрин https://prnt.sc/kw490i

Comment: @Ник, наверное у меня заблокирован этот ресурс. Попробую часиков через 6 из дома открыть.

Comment: добавил на радикал https://d.radikal.ru/d27/1809/be/9f3488b829b7.png

Comment: @Ник, вижу. Надо было в студии открыть меню **View=>Error List**, и оттуда просто скопировать текст ошибки. Это эффективнее чем скриншот делать. Ответ длинный получается, было бы неплохо если бы вы новый вопрс задали по поводу этой ошибки. В комментариях могу только посоветовать написать вот эту строчку в верхней части страницы: `@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding`. Но почему она нужна, и какие еще есть способы рассказать места не хватит. Кстати, у вас ASP.NET Core проект? Я ответ то писал из расчета что ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Да, using помог. Проект Core 2.1 В строке @if ((int)property.Model >= Achs[property.PropertyName] / 3) Ругается на Model "ModelMetadata' does not contain a definition for 'Model' and no extension method 'Model' accepting a first argument of type 'ModelMetadata' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)". Подставил .Order - проект завёлся, но само собой не перебирает поля в модели))). Спасибо за пинок в направлении нужного русла!)

Answer (score 1):

Если я верно понял, у вас есть наборы переменных `Arch1 ... Arch50` и вам надо их как то положить в массив, чтобы завернуть какую то конструкцию в цикл вместо того, чтобы её 50 раз повторять в коде.

Приведу небольшой пример. Допустим, у нас есть переменные

```
int Ach1 = 3;
int Ach2 = 300;
int Ach3 = 500000;
```

Мы можем их положить в массив вот так

```
int[] array = new int[] {Ach1, Ach2, Ach3};
```

После этого можем пройтись по ним циклом

```
foreach (var ach in array)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ach);
}
```

Вывод, как ожидается

```
3
300
500000
```

Comment: Да, отлично. Но честно сказать интересует больше как быть с базой тут же) Вот пример: 
 ()foreach (xWeb.Models.DataBase.Achievements info in ViewBag.info)
    {
  ()if ()info.Ach1 >= @Ach1 / 3) 
  <span class="pull-right glyphicon glyphicon-star text-warning"></span>
 }
 
 В табличке базы данных Achievements все строки так же по порядку. Начиная с Ach1 и заканчивая Ach50.
 Вот эта проблема более болезненна)
 За первый пример огромное спасибо! Прошу прощения, не пойму как тут использовать форматирование.

Comment: @Ник так, постойте. Во первых. поглядите на свой комментарий. Вы можете в нем прочитать код? Я - нет, у меня после 20 часов кодинга и без того глаза болят. Во вторых - вы спрашивали про цикл, сейчас говорите про базы данных - если это разные вопросы, то задавайте второй вопрос отдельно. Если это один и тот же вопрос - то снимайте галку с моего ответа и добавляйте все уточнения в этот вопрос. Я, например, ничего не понял про то, причем тут базы данных и что вы тут пишете за код, которого не писали в вопросе (и почему бы то, что вас интересует больше всего, сразу не указать в вопросе?).